# Error when running application in debug mode from Visual Studio 2012 on windows 8

Tags: debugging, windows-8, visual-studio-2012

When I'm trying to run any type of project using F5 or attaching to a process an error window is displayed displaying the following:

> "*Error when trying to run the project: Unable to start the program
>   ... The microsoft visual studio debugging monitor does not appear to
>   be running on the remote machine. This may be because a firewall is
>   preventing communication to the remote computer...*"

But I'm debugging locally. This happens to some projects but not all. 
I'm on Windows 8, Visual Studio 2012, and using Project configuration ANY CPU.

What should I do in order to debug my application locally using Visual Studio 2012?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading Visual Studio 2012 to SP2 fixed the issue.